# Guice module with type parameters

Tags: java, generics, guice

I spent some time wondering if it is possible to write a guice module 
which itself is parametrized with type T and uses 
its type parameter to specify bindings.

Like in this (not working) example:

```
interface A<T> {} 
class AImpl<T> implements A<T>{} 
interface B<T> {} 
class BImpl<T> implements B<T> {} 

class MyModule<T> extends AbstractModule { 
    @Override 
    protected void configure() { 
        bind(new TypeLiteral<A<T>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<AImpl<T>>(){});
        bind(new TypeLiteral<B<T>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<BImpl<T>>(){}); 
    } 
}
```

I tried different approaches passing trying to pass T to MyModule as instance of 
Class/TypeLiteral but none of them worked. 
Help appreciated.

Regards, Łukasz Osipiuk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For that you will have to build each TypeLiteral from scratch, using `com.google.inject.util.Types`. You could do something like that:

```
class MyModule<T> extends AbstractModule {
    public MyModule(TypeLiteral<T> type) {
        _type = type;
    }

    @Override protected void configure() {
        TypeLiteral<A<T>> a = newGenericType(A.class);
        TypeLiteral<AImpl<T>> aimpl = newGenericType(AImpl.class);
        bind(a).to(aimpl);
        TypeLiteral<B<T>> b = newGenericType(B.class);
        TypeLiteral<BImpl<T>> bimpl = newGenericType(BImpl.class);
        bind(b).to(bimpl);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <V> TypeLiteral<V> newGenericType(Class<?> base) {
        Type newType = Types.newParameterizedType(base, _type.getType());
        return (TypeLiteral<V>) TypeLiteral.get(newType);
    }

    final private TypeLiteral<T> _type;
}
```

Please note that the private method newGenericType() will perform no control on types, it is your responsibility, in `configure()`, to make sure that generic types can be correctly built with that method.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. I knew I had already used this kind of advanced stuff in my guts-event library, so it was not very hard to adapt your example from I had done in the past.

Comment: What should I do if I don't know what the `AImpl` or `BImpl` types are? In my case I am making a library which exposes a generic class and associated guice module.