# Generic Guice Modules

Tags: generics, guice

In Guice 3, I am trying to create a generic Module:

```
public class CSVModule<K> extends AbstractModule implements Serializable {
  public List<Range<K>> searchRange = new LinkedList<Range<K>>();

  @Override protected void configure() {
    bind(new TypeLiteral<List<Range<K>>>(){}).toInstance(searchRange);
  }
}
```

This results in the exception:

```
1) java.util.List<test.Range<K>> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

The searchRange is supposed to be configured from the "outside":

```
module = new CSVModule<Integer>();
module.searchRange.add(new Range<Integer>(-5, 5));
```

However, I have not only Integer search Ranges so I would like to avoid subclassing the CSV Module for every type.

Would be awesome if anyone can help with that.

Comment: Why don't you use Guice MultiBinder? That looks a better fit than usign a List inside each module instance?

Comment: Please check my answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385858/guice-module-with-type-parameters