# How to get class for templated class?

Tags: java, guice

I need to get the class reference for several templates classes for use with guice. For a normal type I can do `String.class` but `List<String>.class`, is a syntax error.

How can I get the class object for a templated class?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776608/typeliteral-injection-with-reflection/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385858/guice-module-with-type-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't, which is why you use [`TypeLiteral`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html):

```
TypeLiteral<List<String>> list = new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {};
```

You can use that in the bindings in the same way as classes.