# Is it possible to send a generic parameter to a Map?

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

Perhaps the title is badly worded and someone with better knowledge could edit it.

I want to create a method `parseFromJSONMap` which parses a JSON file using gson and returns the data as a Map, more specifically a `Map<String, T>` where T is a subclass to a class called `Entity`. Two of the subclasses are defined so far, `Creature` and `Hero` but there might be more later. So if I call

```
parseFromJSONMap(file, Creature.class)
```

it should return a `Map<String, Creature>` and if I call

```
parseFromJSONMap(file, Hero.class)
```

It should return a `Map<String, Hero>` etc.

This is what the method looks like now (it only works for Creatures):

```
public static <T extends Entity> Map<String, T> parseFromJSONMap(File file, Class<T> clazz) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Creature>>(){}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(new FileReader(file), type);
}
```

So instead of `Creature`, I want to put `T`. If I do that and call it like so

```
Map<String, Creature> test = Entity.parseFromJSONMap(somefile, Creature.class);
```

I get `java.lang.Object cannot be cast to heroes.model.Creature`

Is what I want possible?

Edit: The exception occurs when I call any method on `test`, for example `test.get("someCreature")`, so this is a runtime exception.

Comment: it may be worth adding the stacktrace you get

Comment: I think that is the only exception that I get because all I have is a temporary main method in `Creature` that calls `Entity.parseFromJSONMap`.  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to heroes.model.Creature
 at heroes.model.Creature.main(Creature.java:131)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you do this to cause it to blow?

```
public static <T extends Entity> Map<String, T> parseFromJSONMap(File file, Class<T> clazz) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, T>>(){}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(new FileReader(file), type);
}
```

Your problem is that you need to make the type argument concrete when you create the TypeToken otherwise how can it know what type it should be representing? Remember that erasure is [replacing type parameters by their leftmost bound](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101) and that a [super type token](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) (which is what that TypeToken is, as used in Guice & Gson and various other places) is basically a trick that lets you get access to the parameterized type information of the superclass via reflection. Also note the javadoc says

> This syntax cannot be used to create type literals that have wildcard
>   parameters, such as `Class<?>` or `List<? extends> CharSequence>`.

This is basically your situation. The only way out I know of will be creating the type token programatically. For example via `Method.getGenericReturnType` or by looking at the way Guice uses type tokens, at first glance it has a richer set of utility methods for figuring this stuff out. An example of how to do this is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385858/guice-module-with-type-parameters), this uses some guice classes but if you look at the guice source it should be become reasonably obvious what is going on.

Comment: I don't want to include more libraries than necessary. Would it make more sense if I made `parseFromJSONMap` an abstract method returning a normal Map in Entity and then letting each subclass implement it?

Comment: that would be a simple, if verbose, way to solve the problem providing you will always control the types you're creating. The only alternative appears to be extending the library you're using to provide this functionality.

Comment: I guess this is one of the occasions where I would like to have an "abstract static" modifier.
I have temporarily solved the issue by having a GameResourceManager class which initiates everything. GRM first parses each json file in the creatures folder to represent the Creatures, then in the heroes folder to represent the Heroes etc. I don't know if this is a good design, but it shifts the responsibility from the individual classes to a single class and there I will probably have more control over the types I'm creating, like you say.